# How do i create a program that create a user specified notification on a user specified date and time

Tags: windows, vb.net, push-notification

I am trying to create a Visual Basic Windows Forms program that outputs a Windows notification on the date and time specified by the user (so far I have not done the date and time part because of this issue).

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Text
Public Class Notifications
    Sub Main()
        Dim Toast As New Toast_Notification("Good Morning", "My Title")
    End Sub

Class Toast_Notification
    Public Sub New(text As String, title As String)
        Dim sbXML As New StringBuilder()
        sbXML.Append("<toast><visual><binding template =""ToastImageAndText01""><text id = ""1"" >")
        sbXML.Append(title & vbNewLine & text)
        sbXML.Append("</text></binding></visual></toast>")
        Dim XMLDoc As New Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument()
        XMLDoc.LoadXml(sbXML.ToString())
        Dim Toast = New Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification(XMLDoc)
        Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(title).Show(Toast)
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I am trying to do is create a user-specified notification on a user-specified date (for a Windows 10 computer) but I keep getting the error

> System.Exception: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CE506'

Edit 1: console.readline() is already in their to prevent it from closing

Edit 2: An extra pair of speech marks added after my binding

The error code is gone however now no notifications are being displayed

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but your `<binding>` element appears to be missing a set of quotes. Do you mean `<binding template=""ToastImageAndText01"">`?

Comment: Thankyou blackwood, Now the error has disappeared but no notifications are popping up as intended

Comment: Is this a desktop application? If so it will not work, there are some requirements. 1. The app must have a shortcut installed (though not necessarily pinned) to the Start screen or in the Apps view
2. The shortcut must have an AppUserModelID
3. **Desktop apps cannot schedule a toast**
4. All toasts raised by desktop apps are the same system-defined color
5. Desktop apps cannot use web images
6. Desktop app notifications will not appear on the lock screen. Please see more [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh779727(v=win.10))

Comment: Thankyou Codexter, is there any other way I can get the windows system to display out a notification

Comment: I have found a solution to this question